# session based shopping cart

Tags: php, session, while-loop, shopping-cart, array-push

Originally I got it to work fine, in passing the product `id` over, through the `array_push()` function, going from  `addtocart.php` to  `Shoppingcart.php` displaying the items. But when I add more variables/into the `array_push()` function, other that the single  product `id` `$_GET['id']`, ... on the next page that receives this array, it gives me an error.

**The problem is:**
In the original  `$sql` query it was getting the `id` it needs to display the products info from the `array_push()` and display it on to  `Shoppingcart.php`, but when I add more variables/info into the `push_array()` I get an error. Because its confuses the `$sql` query, because of the `WHERE id IN` clause … the `ID` is still in there, now along with the other info(`$_GET['size']` & `$_GET['qty']`), I just don’t know how to access it...

How can I add more info into the push array, but some how define it so I can grab the `id` for my `$sql` query, to get the product info, but also have access to the `size` & `Qty` for my `while()` loop.

**addtocart.php**

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['id']); //working MAIN
header('Location:shoppingCart.php');

How 2: array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['id'], $_GET['size'],  $_GET['qty']); 
//Not Working
```

**shoppingcart.php**

```
    <?php 
    $whereIn = implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']); //working MAIN
    $sql = " SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id IN ($whereIn) "; ?>

 <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

<td  valign="top">
    <div id="sc_itemBox">
        <p class="sc_itemBox_iTEXT"><strong>SIZE:</strong> “”XL?? <em>(Extra Large??)</em></p>
        <div id="sc_itemBox_img"><img src="<?php echo $row['imgThumb'];?>" /></div>
        <p class=<p class="sc_itemBox_iTEXT"><strong>STYLE#</strong><?php echo $row['styleNUM']; ?> </p>
    </div>        
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If you need anymore information to better understand what going on here, just let me know, I tried to do my best to be clear, as not to confuse anyone.

Comment: Are the single quotes written with `‘` instead of `'` (i.e. `$_GET[‘size’]`) or is that just a typo?

Comment: Ok that's what I figured.

Comment: yea i was typing quick just trying to get the gist of it out... :)

Comment: What does your `$_SESSION['cart']` look like when you `print_r($_SESSION['cart']);` I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around what you are trying to do so seeing that array might help me. I think I get it, and I think you need to make your `$_SESSION['cart']` a little more complex.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "29" ["size"]=> string(1) "M" ["quantity"]=> int(1) } }

Comment: Take a look at what I am proposing in my answer. See if it makes sense based on your situation.

Comment: everytime a add to cart btn is clicked it goes to add to cart page, where it creates the array the fowards u to the shopping cart page, where it show u the results.

Comment: Yes, that is fine. In my scenario, that is what it is doing only it stores just ids in one array and qty and size in another.

Comment: How do I pull the id, size, and qty out of the array to use in my qurey and loops, est? That's what i uttimatly want to do, and thak you very much for all the help so far 'Rasclatt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think making your `$_SESSION['cart']` a little more complex may do the trick. Try to separate out your `id` and such into their own array(s). Maybe something like.

**addtocart.php**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        // Store just ids
        // Use array_unique to filter this array
        $_SESSION['cart']['id'] = array_unique($_SESSION['cart']['id']);
        // Save new cart array with that items basics
        $_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]['size'][] = $_GET['size'];
        $_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]['qty'][]  = $_GET['qty'];
        header('Location:shoppingCart.php');
        exit;
    }
```

**shoppingcart.php**

```
// Implode just the id array, no other array in the cart session
// (make sure your addtocart checks for is_numeric so you don't get someone
// injecting sql junk into your db
$whereIn    =    implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']['id']);
$sql        =    "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id IN ($whereIn)";
```

**EDIT:** Here is a way to do it so that you break out your items into sizes (incase you are adding multiple items with the same id but at different sizes and quantities:

```
    function AddToCart()
        {
            // Confirm that an id is being added
            // I am assuming there is an "add" trigger
            if(isset($_GET['add']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
                    // Create the item in the cart
                    // Record size
                    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]['size'][$_GET['size']]['qty']))
                        // Notice here that if there is already this item in the cart
                        // with the exact same size, it will sum
                        $_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]['size'][$_GET['size']]['qty']    +=  $_GET['qty'];
                    else
                        // If not in cart at this size, it will add qty
                        $_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]['size'][$_GET['size']]['qty']    =   $_GET['qty'];
                }
        }

    // Fetch ids for your query 
    function FetchItems()
        {
            if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemcode => $array) {
                            $items[]    =   $itemcode;
                        }

                    return (isset($items))? $items:false;
                }
        }

    // Start the session
    session_start();

    // Add to cart
    AddToCart();
    // This will fetch your ids for your query
    $mysqlIds   =   implode(",",FetchItems());

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($mysqlIds);
    echo '</pre>'; ?>

    <!-- These are just for testing. Will generate different sizes and qty-->
    <a href="?add=true&id=1&size=<?php echo rand(1,12); ?>&qty=<?php echo rand(0,5); ?>">ID 1</a>
    <a href="?add=true&id=2&size=<?php echo rand(1,12); ?>&qty=<?php echo rand(0,5); ?>">ID 2</a>
    <a href="?add=true&id=3&size=<?php echo rand(1,12); ?>&qty=<?php echo rand(0,5); ?>">ID 3</a>
```

**WILL GIVE YOU:**

```
// Session array after adding items to it.
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [size] => Array
                        (
                            [21] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 1
                                )

                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 2
                                )

                            [8] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 0
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 20
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 5
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [size] => Array
                        (
                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 3
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 0
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 4
                                )

                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 6
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 20
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 10
                                )

                            [12] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 2
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 10
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [size] => Array
                        (
                            [11] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 1
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 3
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [qty] => 2
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)

// This is for the ids for your mysql query
2,3,1
```

Comment: BTW... it's working with the id's (thx)... im just trying to figure out why ists double posting the first item into the session

Comment: So when you click add for the first time, it adds a two of the same ids in to the id array?

Comment: Im looking through the code to see what the problem is, i did a var dum... 

array(2) { ["id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "15" } [15]=> array(2) { ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "S" } ["qty"]=> array(1) { [0]=> NULL } } }

Comment: Oooh, no that is just one id array and saves each item into their own array as well

Comment: cos it turning my shopping cart count to two on the fisrt insertion, im using count($_SESSION['cart']); is that the right way to get the count of the shopping cart? so it's basically counting all the arrays in the session, or should i count the qty instead to get the shopping cart count?

Comment: No, count the `$_SESSION['cart']['id']` with the `array_filter()` added

Comment: P.S. just to be sure ... ur positive its just one array in that var-dum is pated above? its says array(2)...   Just checking that all! :)

Comment: Yes, there is and array named `id` that contains one entry (`15`) and an array named `15` which contains that items size and qty'

Comment: Correct for the array filter? echo count(array_filter($_SESSION['cart']['id']));

Comment: Let me modify my answer to propose a way to add to cart. It will just be a bit more indepth...Give me like 10 minutes

Comment: Ok, don't replace what you have, but take a look a the new one. It is a deep array but it breaks down the items a lot more into `size` and `qty`. It allows for same items codes with different sizes and it adds as it goes. The count goes back to count in the cart, no id array. There is a function to grab the ids for your query though

Comment: sorry about that! My internet went down for a system up grade, I apologize for leaving you hanging like that.

Comment: Ok, that alot! let me see how im going to intergrate that with my code i have aready.

Comment: That's alright, take a look at my edit and see if it would be of any value. It has the ability to record more data and still return your 3 ids with the help of a function

Comment: Note though that there is no `id` array anymore. You can go back to counting what's in the cart.

Comment: ok i just plopped it in.. give me a bit to work it out, i'm gonna make a back up and clean up some of the scrap code in the file... BTW I like what you did with the testing part of the code... I just have to figure how to get it to work for me now.

Comment: I'm a bit confused ... about how to use this code with the functions, i was on the right page with you, now im a bit confused. If I can send you the link to the site so you can see what its doing if you dont mind? :)

Comment: Im still up..lol GOOD NEWS! I got everything working, I WANT TO SAY A HUGE THANK YOU, TO YOU, ESPECIALLY FOR HELP ME OUT AT THIS HOUR OF THE NIGHT/MORNING!

Comment: Well I'm sorry to say but I had to hit the hay. But if  what I did answered your question maybe mark my answer correct so no one comes back here thinking its still an open question. Cheers!

Comment: I will make it as answered, P.S. If I do that can I still ask you questions or does it close the post?

Comment: Also I was looking on how to remove an item from the cart, I was using the unset function I figured out how to unset the qnt and the size, but how do I unset the entire id so I can remove and item from the cart?

Comment: So you have like `$_GET['remove'] = 2`, 2 being the id of the product, something like that?

Comment: This is the code for the unset function for the: QTY  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]['qty'][$i])

Comment: Well, if you have it set up the way I have it, then you need to have it go: `unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]['size'][4]['qty']);` This will remove this item from cart, not just adjust the quantity. Also the `[4]` is just arbitrary and would represent the size of the item. So it goes `['cart'](name)->['itemcode'](number)->['size'](name)->['size'](number)->['qty'](name)->value of 'qty'(number)`

Comment: Hey, im back ... i wasn't to sure how to implement the code so I went ahead and continued with other areas of the site, to keep it moving and get the easy stuff out the way... so my question to you is can you kind of explain where the code should go...

Comment: I'm trying to implement functionality to my cart like remove and item, update quantity,  est... I think your code is exactly what im looking for I just don't know where to put it / integrate it into my-site.

Comment: ok Goodnews I got your exact 'addtocart.php' script to work, I just realized I had to define the id $_SESSION['cart']['id'][] = $_GET['id'];, it keep telling me null and i was like .. what the.. now it's working and going to the shopping cart just fine, It's just the 'EDIT: ' part of your script above where does that go ... i'll be on line checking back to see if ur online.

Comment: Glad it works! The Edit stuff basically gives you the ability to transport and access the function to create your shopping cart anywhere on you site. It's all contained in those two functions, but it does organize the array a bit differently.

Comment: hey man .. nice to see you online, im a bit stuck here tonite... can you help? its with you script for this same question.

Comment: p.s. If you can help me out tonight i might be able to finishup the site tonight or tomorrow the I can take a week of to celebrate then get back to wrork. Im so close to being done!

Comment: Ive been working on this project / launch for about 5 months now no stop night & day. so you probably know when i'm coming from. ;\

Comment: What do you have and what do you need?

Comment: When I add a item to the Cart it adds fine, but if I try to add the same item but with a  diffrent size it dosent add to the cart cos of the array unique in the add to cart.php, so how do you add more of the same item ... say just a diffrents size...

Comment: I hope i didn't miss you! I was tinkering around with the ipn and I totally lost track of time ... seems ive started a game of cat & mouse.

Comment: Yeah that's where the functions come in. It will add different sizes like you want

Comment: lol... i can see the logic in the code, im just unsure how to get it to work.

Comment: hmmm ... Is there a way I can send you a direct message with the link to the site.

Comment: ok so I have the add to cart php working perfectly with your array_Uniue and its add it to the cart and displaying fine. just if i add another size it dosent add to cart, now thats where your script comes in... but I dont know how to use it. If you can help me with that i think my carts done, I think.

Comment: so where should i place the 'Edit' Code in the same page as the shopping cart i presume,  should it go above or blow the wile loop withe the results or in a seperate page, thats kind of my problem.

Comment: What you do is include the functions with your page, then put the `AddToCart();` at the top of the page before page load.

Comment: use a php include on the shopping cart page? what do you mean before page laod?

Comment: no because you said "put the AddToCart(); at the top of the page before page load", i just wast sure waht you ment by that...

Comment: Can you send me your file to me and I'll review it and send it back to you?

Comment: AddToCart(); goes at the top of the page.. in a php tag , or like on a body onload function?

Comment: At the top before the html gets output to the page.

Comment: ok I sent you the files, if you any questions let me know, i put the html file in a seperate include file, if you need it let me know.

Comment: ok, i have everything set up with no errors, just how do I trigger the functions from the functions file & 2ndly How do I get the Quantity to display in qty box on the shopping cart page.